# Woocommerce - Subtracting custom field amount from product price in single product, checkout, email invoice and thank you screen

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, price

I want to calculate product price and subtract the amount (defined in my custom field) from product price.
lease note that i'm using variable product and price of each variation is different and i have about 54 variations.
I want to subtract the amount defined in my custom input fields from product total price every where e.g product page, checkout , cart, thank you page and email invoice.
this is code of my custom input field that is showing on product editing page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Register meta boxes.
 */
function zen_register_metaboxes_for_zprotect() {
    add_meta_box(
        'zen_zprotect_product_price',
        'Z Protect+ Prices',
        'zen_url_meta_callback',
        'product',
        'normal', 
        'high'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'zen_register_metaboxes_for_zprotect' );

/**
* 
* Meta box display callback.
*
*/
function zen_url_meta_callback( $post ) {
    ?>
    <div class="conv_meta_box_wrap conv_email_settings_meta">
        <p class="meta-options conv_meta_fields">
            <label for="zen_zprotect_ip12"><strong>Add price for iPhone 12</strong></label><br>
            <input id="zen_zprotect_ip12"
                   type="text"
                   name="zen_zprotect_ip12"
                   style="width: 100%;"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'zen_zprotect_ip12', true ) ); ?>">
        </p>
        <p class="meta-options conv_meta_fields">
            <label for="zen_zprotect_ip12mini"><strong>Add price for iPhone 12 Mini</strong></label><br>
            <input id="zen_zprotect_ip12mini"
                   type="text"
                   name="zen_zprotect_ip12mini"
                   style="width: 100%;"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'zen_zprotect_ip12mini', true ) ); ?>">
        </p>
        <p class="meta-options conv_meta_fields">
            <label for="zen_zprotect_ip12pro"><strong>Add price for iPhone 12 Pro</strong></label><br>
            <input id="zen_zprotect_ip12pro"
                   type="text"
                   name="zen_zprotect_ip12pro"
                   style="width: 100%;"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'zen_zprotect_ip12pro', true ) ); ?>">
        </p>
        <p class="meta-options conv_meta_fields">
            <label for="zen_zprotect_ip12promax"><strong>Add price for iPhone 12 Pro Max</strong></label><br>
            <input id="zen_zprotect_ip12promax"
                   type="text"
                   name="zen_zprotect_ip12promax"
                   style="width: 100%;"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'zen_zprotect_ip12promax', true ) ); ?>">
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function zen_save_metaboxes( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        $post_id = $parent_id;
    }
    $fields = [
        'zen_zprotect_ip12',
        'zen_zprotect_ip12mini',
        'zen_zprotect_ip12pro',
        'zen_zprotect_ip12promax',
    ];
    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        if ( array_key_exists( $field, $_POST ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $field, sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$field] ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'zen_save_metaboxes' );
```

[image showing results of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7b9O.png)

And this is the code i was trying to achecive subtracted price as product total price, based on product variation selection:

```
$product['zen_zprotect_ip12']= get_post_meta( $product->get_the_ID(), 'zen_zprotect_ip12' );
$product['zen_zprotect_ip12mini']= get_post_meta( $product->get_the_ID(), 'zen_zprotect_ip12mini' );
$product['zen_zprotect_ip12pro']= get_post_meta( $product->get_the_ID(), 'zen_zprotect_ip12pro' );
$product['zen_zprotect_ip12promax']= get_post_meta( $product->get_the_ID(), 'zen_zprotect_ip12promax' );
function zen_variation_price_format( $price ) {
//$zprotect_price = $product['zen_zprotect_ip12'];
//$phone_price = $price - $zprotect_price;

$price = $product['zen_zprotect_ip12'];

return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'zen_variation_price_format');
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_price_html', 'zen_variation_price_format' );
```

The above code causes critical error on my site.
any help in this case is very much appreciated. thank you in advance.

Comment: _“The above code causes critical error on my site.”_ - you mean a 500 Internal Server Error? Then go and check the server’s error log! That is _always_ the first thing you have to do when you get a 500, and the cause is not immediately obvious.

Comment: no the error is caused due to second peice of code, when i remove that peice of code from functions.php, everything works fine.

Comment: Well if you are happy with simply removing this code and leaving it at that, then we are done here. If not, and you want to _fix_ the error - then go and do as you were told!

Comment: the error is fixed but my goal to subtract custom amount from variable product price is still not acahieved. i'm looking for that fix.